# Different results on localhost than on remote site

Tags: custom-component, localhost, error

I get the following error on my remote site (hostgator), but not on my local localhost site.  It only happens for the component I am developing, not for the native banners or contacts components.

 Form::loadForm could not load file
--- JROOT/libraries/src/MVC/Model/FormBehaviorTrait.php:94 …

My component has 2 tables, stblrecs and leagues.  Included in installation sql of component, I add example records to stblrecs, but none to leagues.

On the admin view I can open both views, but when I attempt to add a record to either table (on my hostgator site), I get the above error.

I can add and edit records on my localhost site with no errors.

Has anybody ever seen something like this?  It’s as if my hostgator site isn’t finding the forms folder, but my localhost has no problem finding it.  Debugging on my localhost reveals no issues and paths are properly built and maintained.

My remote system information:

- PHP Built On  Linux gator4316.hostgator.com 4.19.150-76.ELK.el7.x86_64
  #1 SMP Wed Oct 7 01:33:43 CDT 2020 x86_64
- Database Type mysql
- Database Version  5.7.23-23
- Database Collation    utf8_unicode_ci
- Database Connection Collation utf8mb4_general_ci
- Database Connection
- Encryption    None
- Database Server Supports  Connection Encryption   Yes
- PHP Version   8.1.20
- Web Server    Apache
- WebServer to PHP Interface    litespeed
- Joomla! Version   Joomla! 4.3.2 Stable [ Bora ] 30-May-2023 16:00 GMT
- User Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64;
  x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0
  Safari/537.36 Edg/114.0.1823.51

My localhost system information:

- PHP Built On   Windows NT DESKTOP-H1CFTTO 10.0 build 19045 (Windows 10) AMD64
- Database Type             mysql
- Database Version              8.0.23
- Database Collation                utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
- Database Connection Collation     utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
- Database Connection Encryption        None
- Database Server Supports Connection Encryption    Yes
- PHP Version                   8.0.14
- Web Server                    Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) PHP/8.0.14
- WebServer to PHP Interface            apache2handler
- Joomla! Version               Joomla! 4.3.1 Stable [ Bora ] 2-May-2023 16:00 GMT
- User Agent                    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/114.0.1823.51

Comment: You most likely have incorrectly cased form file or directory.

Comment: you are correct.  I named the form xml files with initial upper case. i.e., League.xml instead of league.sml.  Still I'd be interested to know why it worked on local server but not remote.  Is it the php version differences, or a configuration setting?

Comment: Linux has a case sensitive filesystem and Windows does not.

Comment: Thanks Sharky.  Good to know.  Yes, my machine runs windows.  Perhaps I can run a Linux shell for testing too.